# Need help, cant explain this part of code in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Dont understand what mean condition of foor loop.
How write this part of code in If/else form.
Thank you.

Comment: That is an enhanced for loop. Now I guess you got the search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code means for each character in the string, if it's not a digit, return false. You can't write it purely in if/else form, as you need a loop to visit each character in the string.